# Should I be generating my own ObjectID for Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

My initial thought was to have MongoDB automatically create the `_id` field. However, the frontend of my app is PHP and I submit a job into Beanstalkd. The backend is picked up by a Python daemon that pulls the necessary info from Beanstalk. What I'm trying to accomplish is so that the user gets redirected to a status page, but I need the `ObjectId` that was used. The only way I can think of accomplishing this is to generate the `ObjectId` as part of the job info. Hence, I have this information handy and I can use it to display the status page.

So my question is, could I run into issues? I figure a timestamp is part of the `ObjectId` therefore it should be unique even if I pre-generate it before inserting into Mongo.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that it won't be a problem to create and attach _id to db by your code rather than mongoDB driver code. If you write your code to generate ID correctly you won't dive in any issue, because it would be quite same or similar algorithm as for mongoDB driver. 
Take a look at [MongoID](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php) class.